# Set page using the org.displaytag.tags.el.ELTableTag

Tags: struts, displaytag

I'm using the `org.displaytag.tags.el.ELTableTag` tag for displaying a list of objects. Is it possible to set the page manually, e.g. to the 6th page. I want to implement a back button which doesn't return to the first page, but to the last page displayed.

Is there a way to read the current page number without accessing the automatically generated page parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in [initParameters](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/displaytag/displaytag/1.2/org/displaytag/tags/TableTag.java#TableTag.initParameters%28%29). There's an internal "pagenumber" attribute which gets set there.

Comment: great, it works. Do you know whether there is a way to get this attribute from the request to know which was the last page? Of course I could access the generated parameter, but as it has a generated id, this wouldn't be a proper solution.